# Passing headers to encrypted hls stream in ffmpeg

Tags: command-line, ffmpeg, encryption, headers, hls

I am using ffmpeg 5.1. I want to save encrypted aes-128 hls in which the decrypting key link is in m3u8 stream link.
I am able to pass headers & get m3u8 file content using :

```
ffmpeg  -headers "Hvar1: hvalue1" -headers "Hvar2: hvalue2" -headers "Hvar3: hvalue3" -i "http://media.link/mediafile.m3u8" -t 30 -c copy output.mkv -loglevel debug
```

M3u8 content is like this :

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:582
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:6
#EXT-X-KEY:METHOD=AES-128,URI="https://media.key.link/live/media-1500.key",IV=0x00080
#EXTINF:5.000,
media-20.ts
#EXTINF:5.000,
media-25.ts
#EXTINF:6.000,
media-30.ts
#EXTINF:5.000,
media-35.ts
#EXTINF:5.000,
media-40.ts
```

-loglevel debug is showing that headers are being passed to fetch content from "http://media.link/mediafile.m3u8".
But the problem is with getting remote key file i.e. https://media.key.link/live/media-1500.key as it needs the same headers to get fetched and those same headers are not getting passed to remote key file url.
I get this error :

```
[http @ 0x01] No trailing CRLF found in HTTP header. Adding it.
[hls @ 0x01] Skip ('#EXT-X-VERSION:3')
[hls @ 0x01] Opening 'https://media.key.link/live/media-1500.key' for reading
[https @ 0x01] HTTP error 403 Forbidden
[hls @ 0x01] Unable to open key file https://media.key.link/live/media-1500.key
[hls @ 0x01] Opening 'crypto+http://media.link/media-20.ts' for reading
[hls @ 0x01] Opening 'crypto+http://media.link/media-25.ts' for reading
[hls @ 0x01] Error when loading first segment 'http://media.link/media-20.ts'
http://media.link/mediafile.m3u8: Invalid data found when processing input
```

How do I pass the headers to remote key file url as well ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead

```
ffmpeg -headers "Hvar1: hvalue1\r\nHvar2: hvalue2\r\nHvar3: hvalue3\r\n" -i "http://media.link/mediafile.m3u8" -t 30 -c copy output.mkv -loglevel debug
```